# How to make one child component render instead of waiting other components in array?

Tags: reactjs

To make the question clear, I will give an small example.
I have two components. A depends on B and there is slow calculation in B.

```
export function A(props) {
  const {infos} = props;
  return (infos.map(info => <B info={info}></B>))
}
```

```
export function B(props) {
  const {info} = props;
  /* some slow and heavy calculation to get the result */

  return (<p>{result}</p>)
}
```

Now A will wait for all Bs calculating, then it will show all results in B.
Is there a way to make A render as soon as any B calulation finishes, which means A will render result one by one.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a snippet so we can test it?

Comment: @Arkellys I have posted the github repo link in chat. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546883/16136765

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not installing a whole repo. :/

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the full/origin code, but I'd guess you do the calculation on component first level block. By that I mean that your heavy calculation is being executed right on when the component "starts".

Then my solution would be to render the component without waiting for something, and defer the `result` value for "later":

```js
export function B(props) {
  const {info} = props;

  const [resultState, setResultState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        /* some slow and heavy calculation to get the result */
        const result = Math.pow(200, 200);

        resolve(result);
    }).then(() => setResultState(() => value)
  }, []);

  return resultState === null ? "I'm loading.." : (<p>resultState</p>);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether I have done things right. But when I try your method, Bs are still not shown one by one.

Comment: @SNORLAX without some more code to look at there is nothing I can help more…

Comment: https://github.com/S-N-O-R-L-A-X/Bridge-Tools/blob/master/src/Components/ShowAllBoards/ShowAllBoards.tsx 
If you are interested, you can visit this. but it is more tricky.  A is ShowAllBoards, B is ShowCards and the heavy calculation is in OfflineBridgeSolver, which is depended by  Showcards.

Comment: @SNORLAX And where is the file with the slow loading? And for this file, could you please also provide the code your tried according to my answer?

Comment: I have tried it in local. SInce it does not work so I have not pushed it to origin. I will post OfflineBridgeSolver in this page.

Comment: ```
function analyzeOffline() {
  // @ts-ignore
  const res = calcDDTable(convertAllHandsToPBN(allHands));
  const table = new Array(4).fill(0).map(() => new Array(5).fill("*"));
  ...
  return table;
 }

 useEffect(() => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const table = analyzeOffline();
   resolve(table);
  }).then((x:any)=>{
   setDDtricks(x);
  })
 }, [allHands]);
```

Comment: @SNORLAX Please modify your question with this code